# If $\gcd(8n^2 + 6n; 8n^2 + 10n) = 20$, find $\text {lcm}(n^2 + n; n^2 + 3n)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm

Today I argued with my math teacher about this:

> $\gcd(8n^2 + 6n; 8n^2 + 10n) = 20$ and we have find $\text {lcm}(n^2 + n; n^2 + 3n)$

Comment: Why not share your attempt on the problem?

Comment: What does Euclid's algorithm tell you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I have understood the problem correctly, given 
$$20=\gcd(8n^2 + 6n; 8n^2 + 10n) =2n\gcd(4n + 3; 4n + 5)=2n\gcd(4n + 3; 2)$$
 we have to find 
$$\text {lcm}(n^2 + n; n^2 + 3n)=n\text {lcm}(n+1; n+3).$$
The first line tells us something about $n$...

P.S. I read from your profile that you are a 8th grade student. So please ask if you need further help.

Comment: yeah, but the problem says that we have to find the exact number. and I think it's pretty impossible to find exact answer

Comment: @Reinstein My answer is a hint. From the first line we have $20=2n\gcd(4n + 3; 2)$, what is the value of $\gcd(4n + 3; 2)$ for any integer $n$?  Then what is $n$?

Comment: @Reinstein Please edit your post, and under the question, write your answer (or what you tried). Without showing any effort the question is going to be closed!!

Comment: thanks, I understood, but how did you get $gcd(4n+3; 4n+5) = gcd(4n+3;2)$?

Comment: $\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,b-a)$ when $b>a$ See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor#Euclid's_algorithm

Comment: @Reinstein If you do not edit you question as I kindly asked you I will be very annoyed.

Comment: what should I change in edit?

Comment: @Reinstein Write the statement in a clear way. Have you solved the problem? Share your attempt on the problem. One more vote and your question will be closed!